# Notepad++ add text between every line

Tags: notepad++

I want to add a text (eg. HELLO) between each Line

For example:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

make it:

```
Line 1
HELLO
Line 2
HELLO
Line 3
HELLO
```

Comment: Thank you all! Is there any explanatory good link about the Logic followed?

Comment: Was any of the answers helpful to you? If so, please mark them. If not, please refine your question so we can improve our answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Press CTRL-H to replace
- in Find what - type *\n*
- in Replace with - type *\nHELLO\n*
- Select *Extended* in Search mode
- Press *Replace All*

Answer (score 0):

A simple search/replace will do the job here, looking for `\r\n` and replacing it with `\r\nHELLO\r\n`. The important thing is to have selected the Extended Search mode (at the bottom of the search/replace dialog), so the control characters can be specified in this way.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be to use a form of Regular Expression in the Find/Replace.  I expect that your sample, used here, is not exactly what you're trying to do, but to solve the sample, try the following in the Find/Replace dialog.

```
([\d]{1})[\s]{1}
```

This will find 1 digit, followed by 1 space, and replace it with the 1 digit, followed by " HELLO "

See an explaination of the regular expression pieces, here: https://regex101.com/r/wW8cG2/1

Comment: The use of a regex is massively overkill for the problem as stated.

Comment: Without the use of a regex, the other answers given could NOT solve the request before you edited his example.  With the newly modified question, a simpler find/replace will suffice.

Comment: My edit was purely re-formatting, so the separate lines were clear.

Comment: FYI: `[\d{1}]` matches a digit or `{` or `}` or `1` that is already included in `\d`

Comment: @Toto My mistake - I moved the quantifier brackets to the right location.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\R)`
- Replace with: `$1HELLO$1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

`\R` stands for any kind of line break, the added lines will have the same line break as the original lines.